# HotModuleReplacementplugin doesn't work with node_modules in a parent folder

Tags: webpack, node-modules, hot-module-replacement

When I'm using the node_modules in a parent folder to using in multiple projects, the HotModuleReplacement doesn't work. If I disable the hot option in dev server it works perfect. Every file that I change, the console just send the following message:

[WDS] Hot Module Replacement enabled.

enter code here[WDS] App updated. Recompiling...

[WDS] App hot update...

Does anyone have any idea, what's the problem?